# bluebird promise.js unexpected token

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, bluebird, tsd

My pc crashed while "task serve" was building angular solution.
After restart this is the following error that occurred.
This error shows on all angular projects on my pc.

```
[14:33:23] Using gulpfile c:\...\gulpfile.js
[14:33:23] Starting 'tsd:install'...
[14:33:23] Starting 'styles'...
[14:33:26] gulp-inject 49 files into index.scss.
[14:33:34] Finished 'styles' after 10 s

Unexpected token
\node_modules\tsd\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:87
    if (resolver !== INTERNAL) this._resolveFromResolver(resolver);
                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
at Object.parse (native)
    at c:\...\node_modules\tsd\build\http\HTTPCache.js:131:39
```

Comment: Did you uninstall what you had installed and then reinstall/build from scratch?  If you crashed in the middle of a build, then something likely got hammered in the build so you need to start the install/build over.

Comment: I did reinstall my Windows 10 and all was working